# Extracting rightmost N bits of a double in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have some **natural** big number in double. I need to get 30 rightmost bits of it (of integral part).
If it was integer the operation was:

```
var & 0x3FFFFFFF
```

I can implement some functions for the purpose, but I need some simple solution. Is there one?

*edit:

All the answers doesn't work for me.
I'll try to explain: for example I have double x = 9362446620820194.0000, 30 rightmost bits of integral part of that number is the number 957350626.

I could use uint64_t instead of double, but I need support for 32 bit systems.

p.s. I mean simple binary number representation, not the machine (memory)

Comment: The 30 rightmost bits of what? The significand? That will be some part of a scaled log base 2 value. What about the exponent and the sign bit?

Comment: They only don't work because it seems you don't understand what it is you are asking for. You might start by reading [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) on IEEE-754 binary 64 format.

Comment: You can use `uint64_t` on 32 bit systems.

Comment: talonmies, Ok, in the question I mean the actual binary number representation, not machine (memory) representaion. If the double x = 15.00000 and I need 2 rightmost bits of it I mean the repr. of number (of integral part) is 1111 in binary and i need here 11 -> 3.

Comment: If I can use uint64_t, so it is the solution for me. But could you explain for, how could I use uint64_t on 32 bit systems? Just for understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 8-bit `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char const *p = (unsigned char const *)&var;
long rightmost30 = (p[sizeof(double) - 4] & 0x3F) << 24
                 |  p[sizeof(double) - 3] << 16
                 |  p[sizeof(double) - 2] << 8
                 |  p[sizeof(double) - 1];
```

Though really, you should have a look at `frexp` and related functions.

Comment: This will only work on big-endian systems, since you assume that the rightmost bits are always in the last bytes.

Comment: @interjay: I just assumed the OP meant the rightmost bits in the memory representation, since otherwise the operation doesn't make much sense for floating point types.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to look at the rightmost bits of the format defined by IEEE-754, which would correspond to the rightmost bits of the significand. This would be stored in the first bytes in little-endian architectures. Of course, we won't know what the OP actually needs unless he tells us, and since he won't answer requests for clarification I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 0):

The casting hack:

```
float var = 0.2987647892;
uint32_t bit_repr = *(uint32_t *)&var;
uint32_t masked = bit_repr & 0x3FFFFFFF;
```

Comment: I think this violates the strict aliasing rule and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Even wanting to extract bits from a float is undefined IMHO, as you can't know what implementation the compiler uses...

Comment: gettings bits from a float gives *implement-defined* behavior, not UB.